# Iterated integral to error function

Tags: integration, error-function, integration-by-parts, iterated-integrals

> For $n\ge1,a>0$ we define:
>   $$I_{n,a}=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{(1+x^2/a)^n}$$
>
> This question comes in two parts:
>
> Proving that this integral converges, and that:
>   $$I_{n+1,a}=\frac{2n+1}{2n}I_{n,a}$$
>
> and the second part is proving that $$\lim_{n\to
>  \infty}I_{n,n}=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}dx$$

Now, using integration by parts gave me this:
$$I_{n,a}=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\frac{2x^2}{a}n}{(1+x^2/a)^{n+1}}dx$$ which is where I got stuck.

For the second part it is easy to see that $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{(1+x^2/n)^n}=e^{-x^2}$ but how do I justify the limit of the whole integral?

Thanks.

Comment: The $a$ parameter is quite irrelevant and the integral $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{(1+x^2)^n}$ is simple to compute by integration by parts or other techniques.

Comment: $a$ must be positive, so let $a=b^2$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Well simple is a relative term. I obviously tried integration by parts (as I've written in my question), but wasn't sure how to continue.

Comment: It's not an easy task. Mathematica gives the indefinite integral in terms of hypergeometric special function and the improper converges to $\dfrac{\sqrt{a\pi } \,\Gamma \left(n-\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma (n)}$ and the recurrence relation is $I_{n+1,a}=\dfrac{2 n-1}{2 n}\,I_{n,a}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have found that partial integration yields the result:

$$I_{n,a}=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\frac{2x^2}{a}n}{(1+x^2/a)^{n+1}}dx$$

You can then write this as:

$$I_{n,a}=2n\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\frac{x^2}{a}+1-1}{(1+x^2/a)^{n+1}}dx=2n\left(I_{n,a}-I_{n+1,a}\right)$$

Solving for $I_{n+1,a}$ yields:

$$I_{n+1,a} = \frac{2n-1}{2n} I_{n,a}$$

Then to prove that you can take the limit inside the integral, you can use theorems such as the [dominated convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem). Since by the binomial theorem:

$$\left(1+\frac{x^2}{n}\right)^n = 1 + x^2 + \frac{n-1}{2} x^4\cdots \geq1+x^2 $$

we have:

$$f_n(x) = \frac{1}{\left(1+\frac{x^2}{n}\right)^n}\leq \frac{1}{1+x^2}$$

The condition in Lebesgue's Dominated Convergence Theorem that $f_n(x)$ be dominated by an integrable function is then met, therefore the limit of the integral of $f_n(x)$ is given by the integral of the limit function.

Comment: Great answer! Thanks!
The first integral (the iterated one) converges because after the integral is iterated to $I_1$ we get that it is $o(\frac{1}{1+x^2})$ which converges at $+ - \infty$?

Comment: @Mickey Yes, $I_n$ converges because the integrand can be bounded by $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$, but that the limit can be moved inside the integral requires more work, with Dominated Convergence Theorem it's easy but this is not an elementary theorem. You could use uniform convergence by splitting the integral in two parts, from -R to R and the region outside that interval. Then on -R to R you have uniform convergence and you can make the integral over the complement arbitrarily small, so it seems to me that this should yield a rigorous proof using only elementary methods.